# How to use CDN?

Tags: cdn

How to call the product images, skin ( CSS, images, js) from subdomain.

Example :

```
www.media.example.com/media 
www.media.example.com/skin
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a ready-to-go solution I would go with the OnePica module that offers several integrations with CDNs from different vendors.

*"Currently, the extension integrates with Amazon S3, Coral CDN, Mosso/Rackspace Cloud Files, and any CDN, server or service that supports FTP, FTPS, or SFTP. "*

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/onepica-imagecdn-1.html

It's easy to configure and the code is pretty good.

Comment: +1 For OnePica ease of use to get Images on most any CDN easily. However, JS/CSS isn't implemented. Also here's a github link since connect is cumbersome https://github.com/onepica/imagecdn

Comment: I dont recommend this module because it does not support load balance.

Comment: How to set font icon url using cdn server in magento2?

Answer (score 0):

To call skin/media/js from different domains you can edit the base urls under System -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Unsecure. e.g.

[image]

Secure domains can probably be left as normal so that you dont need to worry about SSL certs.

Obviously you also need to set up the domain names, they will need to point to your CDN. The CDN setup will depend on your provider.

IMHO another must with a CDN is a method of invaliding your JS and CSS files from Magento. A good way to do this is to change the url of the asset, this means that the CDN will see it as a different file affectively forcing a reload. [This](https://github.com/diglin/Diglin_UIOptimization) extension for example will add a timestamp to the url of your files when you clear your JS/CSS cache in Magento.